# How to change foreground color of a ttk button that is disabled?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

When I disable a button the color change automatically to black.
This is the code :

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root=Tk()

style=ttk.Style()
style.configure('TButton', foreground='red')
bu1=ttk.Button(root, text="Hello world")
bu1.grid(row=0, column=0)

bu2=ttk.Button(root, text="Hello world2")
bu2.grid(row=1, column=0)

bu1.state(['disabled'])
bu2.state(['disabled'])

root.mainloop()
```

Any help?

Comment: use eventlistener to do so

Comment: I'm new to python, How I can use it ? @Seenivasan

Comment: refer http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm and https://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_events_binds.php. These are helpful

Comment: @Seenivasan: You don't need event listeners

Comment: @BryanOakley great. i saw how using your answer. thnks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a ttk button, you can map certain attributes to different button states with the `map` method of the style object.

For example, to change the colors when the button state is `"disabled"`, you can set the color like this:

```
style.map(
        "TButton",
        foreground=[("disabled", "black")]
)
```

For more information see [50.2. ttk style maps: dynamic appearance changes](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-map.html) on the New Mexico Tech tkinter documentation, and also [Styles and Themes](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/styles.html) on tkdocs.com